# CSS works in an external file but not in the main file itself

Tags: css, slashdot

I have this problem in my SlashDot Menu.

I want to change the picture with a PHP if condition and i understand you cannot put PHP in a css file.

So i have excluded the snippet and put it in the main file.

However, the picture isn't shown ( the bgcolor does change).
Any idea why this would happen?

Here's the css of the SlashDot:

```
div.sdmenu {
width: 150px;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
background: url(bottom.gif) no-repeat  right bottom;
color: #fff;
}
div.sdmenu div {
background: url(title.gif) repeat-x;
overflow: hidden;
}
div.sdmenu div:first-child {
background: url(toptitle.gif) no-repeat;
}
div.sdmenu div.collapsed {
     height: 25px;
}
div.sdmenu div span {
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    background: url(expanded.gif) no-repeat 10px center;
        background-position: 95%;
   cursor: default;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
div.sdmenu div.collapsed span {
background-image: url(collapsed.gif);
background-position: 95%;
}
div.sdmenu div a {
padding: 5px 10px;
background: #eee;
display: block;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
color: #066;
}
div.sdmenu div a.current {
background : #ccc;
}
```

And this is the snippet in the main file:

```
div.sdmenu div a:hover {
background : #066 url(linkarrow.gif) no-repeat right center;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

this is in a "style type='text/css'" tag but i just didn't find how to insert html tags in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the background images path according to the php file, where css is written

Comment: God, how could I forget this.. Thanks a lot! this fixed it.